# Exchangelib: Create subfolder of subfolder of inbox

Tags: python, exchangelib

Hello I'm currently working with exchangelib.
Right now I want to create a subfolder of a subfolder of the inbox and I don't know if it's possible, yet. So I just want to ask if anyone knows more about my problem?
My code for creating a subfolder of the inbox is simply:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, Folder

credentials = Credentials('test.example@mail.com', 'password')
account = Account('test.example@mail.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
folder = Folder(parent=account.inbox, name="subfolder_name")
folder.save()
item.move(folder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating subfolders is possible using exchangelib, and your example should work. If you want to create a sub-subfolder, just use the subfolder as parent:

```
subfolder = Folder(parent=account.inbox, name="subfolder_name")
subfolder.save()
subsubfolder = Folder(parent=subfolder, name="subsubfolder_name")
subsubfolder.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer.

Comment: Have you seen the new question I asked right below here?
Don't wanted to create a new ticket for the same problem.

Comment: You should really post that as a comment instead, because it's not an answer to the original question.

Comment: yes you are right, but I couldn't show the code as code then or is it possible in any way in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I can test the code, because the CASError as mentioned in Github is gone at least for today, I get a "ValueError: Unsupported type  for value None on elem " when I run the code. 
My code is:

```
 subfolder = Folder(parent=account.inbox, name="RFS")
 subsubfolder = Folder(parent=subfolder, name="RFS_1150-1199")
 subsubfolder.save()
 folder = Folder(parent=subsubfolder, name=wordfile)
 folder.save()
 item.move(folder)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace so we can see exactly where the exception occurs.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't try it out right now, because of the CASError, but I know that the problem occurs in this line: "subsubfolder = Folder(parent=subfolder, name="RFS_1150-1199")" as far is I can remember

Comment: You probably need to also set the `account` argument when creating the Folder.

Comment: Sorry that I haven't answered your comment till now, but I had some other tasks to do in the past weeks.
How can I set the account argument? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Try `Folder(account=account, parent=account.inbox, name="RFS")`

Comment: Okay now it works out really fine with that Code:
folder = Folder(account=account, parent=account.inbox, name="RFS")
folder.save()
subfolder = Folder(account=account, parent=folder, name="RFS_1150-1199")
subfolder.save()
subsubfolder = Folder(account=account, parent=subfolder, name=item.subject)
subsubfolder.save()
item.move(subsubfolder)
Again thanks for helping me out.

Comment: And how can I create a new subfolder of my subfolder in a new run, to move the next incoming email over there? I only get a ValueError while running this: subfolder = Folder(account=account, parent=folder, name="RFS_1150-1199")
        subsubfolder = Folder(account=account, parent=subfolder, name="RFS_1195")
        subsubfolder.save()

Comment: You'll have to post the ValueError. Also, if you're not on the latest version of exchangelib already, try upgrading to 1.11.4.

Comment: ValueError: Unsupported type <class 'NoneType'> for value None on elem <Element 'm:ParentFolderId' at 0x000000000C03CEF8>, I've already upgraded exchangelib to 1.11.4

Comment: Probably you forgot to save `subfolder`. At least your example code in the original question doesn't do that.

Comment: The problem is, that if I save the folders again in the second run, I get the "ErrorFolderExists: A folder with the specified name already exists., Could not create folder RFS." error, what I want is just to get into the subfolder and create another folder into that

Comment: Then just try to get the folders by name first. E.g.: `subfolder = account.inbox / 'RFS'`. If that fails with `ErrorFolderNotFound`, then create the folder instead: `subfolder = Folder(parent=account.inbox, name="RFS").save()`.

Comment: The second example is basically the same way, I've tried it before so that doesn't work.
But the first example you gave me worked out fine and now I can create another folder as I wanted it to, so hopefully for the last time now, thank you very much for all the help.